# Check contents of RC file

Tags: file, hadoop, hive

I am trying to investigate the working of RC file and hence stored the file in hadoop cluster using row group size as 3 bytes to ensure my data is stored in 2-3 rowgroups.

After loading, inorder to check how the contents are organized in my file, I downloaded the file to be in RC file format and used `xxd /Path/To/Downloaded/File` to open it. The content which was in hexadecimal format is displayed but I hope there was some other format too in the same file due to which we are not able to check content.

The file in text and binary format opened using xxd is as follows;

[image]

Could someone help me understanding the contents of file in RC format.

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score 0):

There is  hive utility `rcfilecat` to read RC file. Something like:

```
ggk@hadoop4:~/Downloads$ hive --rcfilecat 000000_0
```

References:

1. [Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/RCFileCat)
2. [Java doc](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/cli/RCFileCat.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see the file content as is. rcfilecat deserializes the data and rearranges in record format. I used the file to see contents.

```
sudo xxd /path/to/downloaded/file
```

Thanks,
Sree